# How do you set up a Kotlin multi-platform build?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin

I'd like to build the same kotlin source code into javascript and java (android). Is there a standard way to achieve this?

Comment: You mean exactly the same code for Android and JS? You won't get that. The most you can get is sharing the same code base but not the platform specific code (like JS's DOM manipulation and Android's Activity related code)

Comment: right - a lot of the logic in the project is not platform specific. platform specific stuff like dom manipulation and so on would be built in bog standard modules

Comment: Then just make a module for the common logic and 2 separate ones depending on the common one with platform specific code

Comment: yes - so my question is - how should such a module be structured? is there a standard way handle this kind of problem in gradle, for example?

Comment: Are you using Intellij? I can write an answer in a moment

Comment: I am indeed - i was kinda hoping the answer would be more build-tool biased but an intellij solution would be fine too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a project in IntelliJ. Select a Gradle project and then Java (and whatever else you want)

[image: IntelliJ new project menu]

2. Create 3 new Gradle modules: `common`, `android-specific` and `js-specific`. Make sure they are added as module to your main module

[image: Adding new module]

[image: Adding new module part 2]

3. Press next, then finish (and repeat for `android-specific` and `js-specific`)
4. Remove `settings.gradle` from `common`, and the other 2 modules as you aren't going to need them
5. Make sure these 3 new modules are added to the main "parent" module's `settings.gradle`. It should look more less like this:

   ```
   rootProject.name = 'parent'

   include ':common'
   include ':android-specific'
   include ':js-specific'
   ```
6. Edit `common`'s module dependency (`build.gradle` file, line 24 for *me*) from `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8` to `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib` so it's not platform-specific.
7. If you really want to be sure you've done everything right go to View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle

[image: View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle]

8. You should see the Gradle menu and it should look like this

[image: What it should look like]

The gradle config should also work without IntelliJ (or Android Studio) but I didn't test it

Comment: I don't think you can use Kotlin (Java) `common` module as a dependency of a Kotlin (JS) `js-specific` module.

Comment: To make this work, I added sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += '../core/src/main/java'
} to the js-specific/android-specific libraries.

Comment: @Ilya it should be okay now. I've added a 6th point in which you make common's module Kotlin dependency not platform-specific (`kotlin-stdlib` instead of `kotlin-stdlib-jre8`)

Answer (score 2):

Official multi-platform support for Kotlin hasn't been released yet. If you'd like to stay up to date on it I reccomend following the [#multiplatform channel on the Kotlin Slack](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/messages/C3PQML5NU/).